# POST request contains no 'body' field with Satellizer, Express and google auth

Tags: node.js, satellizer

I am working on my first app using Satellizer that contains a NodeJS/Express back and an AngularJS front. I want my users to log in with their Google account.

The front-end is at port 8000 and I have configured it like so :

```
app.config(function($authProvider) {
  $authProvider.google({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google',
    clientId: 'id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  })
});
```

For the back (port 3000), i followed the github repo exemple. [here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js)

```
app.post('/auth/google', function(req, res) {
  var accessTokenUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
  var peopleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect';
  var params = {
    code: req.body.code,
    client_id: req.body.clientId,
    client_secret: config.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
 };
 ...
```

When I click the "log in" button, the pop up pops up, I can use my credentials and it closes. But I am not logged and there is an error in the back:
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined.'

One console.log() later, I found that the problem is that **req.body is empty**. And that is where I am stuck. Am I missing a step?

Here are the requests send to Express :

[ 1531831850948 ]  OPTIONS   /auth/google

[ 1531831851007 ]  POST   /auth/google

I have also enable CORS

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context is missing, but my guess is you need a body parser middleware.

Check out `body-parser` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)), and in your app use it like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.end('you posted:\n' + JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

This example will send back the post payload.

Comment: @Moulissse Glad I could help. :)